# How to create floating action button menu behaviors with recycler views?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I want to animate my recycler view items as they are being added. Not as I scroll, or after the items have been added. The behavior I am trying to mimic is similar to when you have a FloatingActionMenu and you add FloatingActionButtons to that menu. The menu opens up, displaying the items one by one. How do I accomplish this behavior? I am not using FloatingActionMenu or FloatingActionButtons because I would like to inflate more complex views. As you can see, these menus are restricted

https://forum.ionicframework.com/uploads/default/original/1/3/130fe3336b32906959f2ab00e71c276c5acc9ca4.jpg

I have tried adding animations in onBindViewHolder, but this is too late. The items all add at the same time and the animations all take place at the same time instead of sequentially. The only idea that came to mind was to add items to the adapter one by one, and utalize notifyDataSet change, but I wanted to pick the brain of the community to see if there is a better approach. Here is my adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final static int FADE_DURATION = 10000; // in milliseconds
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mContent;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] content) {
        mContext = context;
        mContent = content;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvText.setText(mContent[position]);
        // Set the view to fade in
        setScaleAnimation(holder.itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContent.length;
    }

    private void setFadeAnimation(View view) {
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(FADE_DURATION);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    private void setScaleAnimation(View view) {
        ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim.setDuration(FADE_DURATION);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am initializing and sending data to my adapter

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, mContent);
    rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Some other things I have tried is to control the timing of the items as they are added. I tried using setItemAnimator and then set the addDuration for the items. None of this works as expected.

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, mContent);
    DefaultItemAnimator animation = new DefaultItemAnimator();
    animation.setAddDuration(100000); // << this attribute seems to make no difference
    rvItems.setItemAnimator(animation);
    rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: You probably want to create an [`ItemAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html). Note you don't have to start from scratch, it might be enough to extend one of the existing subclasses listed on that page.

Comment: @Karakuri the itemAnimator only seems to work on scrollable items. So when I scroll, the animation to take place on the first item added upon scroll. I need to intercept the items before they are added and binded.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "scrollable" items. The docs suggest it can animate item additions, moves, changes, and deletions.

Comment: The effects apply when you scroll. So if there are 10 items, and 5 items visible to the user. When you scroll to the 6th item, the animation applies to that. The initial 5 items do not receive any animations from ItemAnimator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how this is possible, I have come up with a solution using handlers. Essentially, you want to insert items one by one. Your Handler is what allows this to happen.

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mItemCounter++;
                ArrayList<Model> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mItemCounter; i++) {
                    if (i < Model.description.size()) {
                        temp.add(Model.description.get(i));
                    }
                }

                if (mItemCounter < Model.description.size()) {
                    if (mItemCounter == 1) {
                        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, temp);
                        rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    } else {
                        mAdapter.insert((mItemCounter - 1), temp.get(mItemCounter - 1));
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 150);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 175);
```

Add an insert method to your adapter so that you can add items one by one, sequentially.

```
public void insert(int position, Model model) {
    mModel.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

The remainder of the setup is dependent upon what you want to do. I wanted my menu to open from bottom up, so I had to also make updates to LayoutManager. First I reversed the layout, and set stack to from end to false. This allows for the desired effects similar to Floating Action button opening from bottom up.

```
    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```